# Selectlist Dropdown

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to create a dropdown with three items:

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3

I wish I could create a model for Items 1, 2 and 3 but I need to instead use a selectlist or viewbag and use ienumerable, dropdownlist.

Items 1, 2 and 3 exist in a table and I'm trying to pass the selected value as 1 and the unselected values as zero.

Could you please tell me what I'd put in my model, view and controller to make this work?

Here's what I've got:

```
<div>
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.ItemModel, new SelectList(Model.ItemModel, "Name",     "Number"), "-- Select One--", new { @class = "selector" })
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Just updated with what I've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do using Knockout and Javascript:
Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ChuckApplication.Controllers
{
    public class SelectlistController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Selectlist/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ProcessSelection(string selectedOption, string[] availableOptions)
        {
            //Do whatever you want with the selection result, I recommend you use a repository to handle it. 


            return Json("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ViewModel.Selectlist.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: availableOptions,  value: selectedOption" style="width: 177px !important"></select>

<button title="Process Selection" data-bind="click: ProcessSelection"></button>
```

Javascript ViewModel:

```
 function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.selectedOption = ko.observable();

        self.availableOptions = ko.observableArray([
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3"
        ]);

        self.ProcessSelection = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Selectlist/ProcessSelection',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ selectedOption: vm.selectedOption(), availableOptions: vm.availableOptions() }),
                success: function (data) {                
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }


    }


    var vm; //View Model

    $(document).ready(function () {
        vm = new ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);


    })
```